# Error of t1000 does not exist

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run a stored procedure from my `C#`, I keep getting an error of:

> A cursor with the name t1000 does not exist

Here is my SQL syntax, but it looks to me like the cursor t1000 does exist?

```
Select emcd 
INTO #UpdateThese
from dailylistedinformation
WHERE CAST(RescheduledDate As Date) = CAST(GETDATE() As Date)

Declare @t1000 int

DECLARE t1000 CURSOR FOR  
SELECT emcd 
FROM #UpdateThese

OPEN t1000   
FETCH NEXT FROM t1000 INTO @t1000   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN       
  DELETE FROM production
  WHERE emcd = @t1000
  INSERT INTO production (name, address, phone, email, zip, city, state)
  SELECT name, address, phone, email, zip, city, state
  from dailylistedinformation
  where CAST(RescheduledDate As Date) = CAST(GETDATE() As Date)
   FETCH NEXT FROM t1000 INTO @t1000   
END   

CLOSE t1000   
DEALLOCATE t1000
```

And this is my C# how I am calling it, it hits the catch block everytime and produces the above error:

```
private void DoSomethingCrazy()
{
  DoSomethingCrazy();
}

public DataSet DoSomethingCrazy()
{
  _dataSet = new DataSet();  
  SqlQueryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  SqlQueryBuilder.Append("exec dbo.runstoredprocedure ");
  _dataSet = ExecuteSqlQuery(databaseConnection, SqlQueryBuilder.ToString());
  return _dataSet;  
}

public DataSet ExecuteSqlQuery(string connectionString, string sqlQuery)
{
  try
  {              
    _connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[connectionString].ToString();     
    _sqlDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    _sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, _sqlDatabaseConnection);
    _sqlDatabaseConnection.Open();
    _sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;    
    _dataSet = new DataSet();
    _sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_sqlCommand);            
    _sqlDataAdapter.Fill(_dataSet, "Data");
    return _dataSet;
  }
  catch (Exception exception) { throw exception; }
  finally
  {
    _sqlDatabaseConnection.Close();
    _sqlCommand.Dispose();
    _sqlDataAdapter.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree, this code should not generate this error.   Can you post your real code?

Comment: @TabAlleman - working on it now...

Comment: Can you let us know what code is in "--Do Some Stuff", do you have a comment or do you really have stuff in there? Can you post the stuff?

Comment: @Phani & Tab Alleman - take a look at Edit

Comment: I still don't see anything that should cause that error.   Maybe the error is caused by some line in your stored procedure that you are not showing.

Comment: You can try: `_sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` in your `ExecuteSqlQuery`...and do not forget to remove the `exec `